# Storybook: Render a component by clicking on a link (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I've got a component, 'Dialog', that renders a modal dialog box basically, when a user clicks on a link or button to invoke/open the dialog. I'm building a storybook component for the Dialog component, and so I need to be able to have a clickable HTML element (anchor tag or button, preferably anchor tag) and open the Dialog component when that clickable HTML element is clicked. I don't know how to go about this in Storybook.

Here is my storybook element as it exists so far:

```
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Dialog> = (args) => <Dialog {...args} />;

export const Regular = Template.bind({});

Regular.args = {
    type:"regular",
    show: false,
    children: "Content of Dialog Box",
    dismissable: true,
    classNames: "",
    maxWidth: "1000px",
    displayBoxShadow: true,
    renderOnLoad: false,
}
```

An example of an implementation of this component/story would be a Log In button that, when clicked, would render a slide-out dialog with appropriate fields (children). I'm trying to implement the Dialog part of the story, as the Dialog component is invoked when another HTML object on page is clicked/interacted with.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, a Storybook story can be any React component and is not limited to being the bare component that you're show-casing. Simply create a thin wrapper component around your real story with a button:

```js
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Dialog> = (args) => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
            <>
                <Button onClick={ () => setOpen(true) }>
                    Open dialog
                </Button>
                <Dialog 
                    { ...args } 
                    show={open}
                    onClose={ () => setOpen(false) } 
                />
            </>
    )

}
```

You can use the same pattern to extend the experience of your Storybook components with more real-world contexts than just the plain component itself.

Full toy example working fine in Storybook 6.4.22:

```js
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react/types-6-0';
import { Button, Dialog } from "@material-ui/core";

interface TestProps {
    open: boolean
    text: string
    onClose: () => void
}

const Test: FC<TestProps> = props => (
    <Dialog open={ props.open } maxWidth={ "lg" } fullWidth onClose={ props.onClose }>
        { props.text }
    </Dialog>
)

export default {
    title: 'Test',
    component: Test
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<Omit<TestProps, "open" | "onClose">> = props => {

    const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={ () => setOpen(true)}>Click me</Button>
            <Test open={ open } onClose={ () => setOpen(false) }text={ props.text }/>
        </>
    )
}

export const ExampleStory = Template.bind({});
ExampleStory.args = {
    text: "This is an example"
};
```

If something is not working in your example, then there is some other problem not related to this method of building a story. Try to generalize from it; start with a simpler component and make it work and take it step by step.

Comment: This sort-of works. Basically I'm getting an error message that I can't really find resolution on, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')
    at http://localhost:6006/main.iframe.bundle.js:15008:45
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_loadable_component_dist_loadable_esm_js-node_modules_storybook_addon-act-60608c.iframe.bundle.js:113906:20)"

Comment: Then there is something else that doesn't work... I will extend my example ...

Comment: I'll have to look at your updated answer. Our "Dialog" component is a custom component, not the material-ui component.

Comment: I know it is but I don't have access to it obviously :) And if it's a well-written component, it should work like any other component :) If it's not thousands of thousands of lines, you can share it via some codesandbox perhaps .. Also, as I said, this only solves THIS problem so try to start with a more basic component and make sure that you can get this strategy working and then find out why it doesn't work with your component.

Comment: One of the args I didn't list, "initialFocus", was causing the error message I was getting. It required a value of { current: null } and now the error message is gone. Thanks for your help.